# Элементарный пример Retrofit2 JSON android studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, post, retrofit

Подскажите, пожалуйста, элементарный пример работы Retrofit2, в сети примеров куча, но все со своими подвохами...

Нужен самый простой пример, допустим на сервере лежит файл `number.json,` в который POST запросом, при нажатии на кнопку (button), нужно записать число введенное вручную в ЕditТext, например `0123456`, и чтобы каждый раз при вводе нового числа они записывались в массив на сервере, и создать вторую кнопку, которая заберет этот массив с сервера и выведет в ТextView.

Comment: Вы описываете, кажется, совсем не простой пример. Вы не сказали ничего про имеющееся у вас API. Видимо, его нет. А без него ретрофит бесполезен по большей части, т.к. на работу с ним рассчитан. Чтобы манипулировать содержимым файла на сервере вам нужен код на сервере, сам retrofit этого делать не будет. Он суть лишь красивая обёртка над http запросами.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как должен выглядеть API?

Comment: Это очень сложный вопрос) Кратко - так, как вам нужно. Если длинно - вам надо поднимать сервер web-приложений (tomcat, apache, nginx), в нём запускать программу (которую вам надо вручную написать с нуля), которая будет на определённом порту слушать входящие соединения, совершать определённые действия и выдавать ответ запрашивающему. На Spring, например, такое сделать можно за пару минут, если до этого потратить пару недель на его изучение (пару недель, если есть достаточный уровень в программировании)

Comment: Т.е., если у вас нет готового API то и Retrofit вам не нужен. Если просто хотите его изучить - сначала найдите общедоступный API и с ним эксперементируйте. Или свой API делайте, если умеете. Если нет - то это займёт слишком много времени, т.е. будет не эффективно в смысле изучения либы под андроид.

Comment: Спасибо за информирование))